# Deleting /etc/machine-id in ubuntu-minimal-cloudimg for proxmox template

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtual-machine, disk-image, proxmox

I am trying to make a template for my Ubuntu VMs mostly by following Techno Tim's instructions [here.](https://docs.technotim.live/posts/cloud-init-cloud-image/) I differ from Tim by wanting to also install qemu-guest-agent so I can get the IP of the vm without having to do it manually. I do this before importing the .img by using the command `virt-customize -a focal-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img --install qemu-guest-agent`. But unfortunately this does me the favor of setting the machine-id, which I do not want in my template. Now, I could also run `virt-customize -a focal-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img --delete /etc/machine-id` as well as in /var/lib/dbus/machine-id which does the trick and deletes it. But unfortunately during boot of any new VM from that, the system boots with many errors because machine-id is not there and for some reason /etc is mounted as read only. Is there any way to fix this?

I can get around this by instead of deleting with virt-customize, I can put in a firstboot script through virt-customize that deletes and regenerates a machine-id with a reboot to make it take effect, but this seems like a less than ideal way to do this. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not delete `/etc/machine-id`.  Instead, truncate it with a command like `truncate -s 0 /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id`.  The `machine-id` file does not get created if it is deleted, but it will get populated with a new value if it is empty.

**links**

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1508766

> Indeed /etc/machine-id must at least exist (empty is okay) in order to
> regenerate it -- then systemd will create a new one in a temporary
> location in /run, bind-mount /etc/machine-id to it, and
> systemd-machine-id-commit.service will then write it to
> /etc/machine-id once the fs becomes read-write

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much! I used the command `virt-customize -a focal-minimal-cloudimg-amd64.img --install qemu-guest-agent --truncate /etc/machine-id` in case anyone else needs it. It seems`virt-customize` doesn't create /var/lib/dbus/machine-id because it said it didn't exist when i tried to delete it.